# Parse received data as json by fluentd

Tags: fluentd

I am trying to receive data by fluentd from external system thats looks like:
data={"version":"0.0";"secret":null}

Response is:
400 Bad Request
'json' or 'msgpack' parameter is required

If i send (can not change real source) same string with "json" instead of "data" (like json={"version":"0.0";"secret":null}), everything is OK. How can i config fluentd to accept it same way? Thanks.

example of fluent.conf:

```
<source>                                                  
  @type http                                              
  port 24224                                              
  bind 0.0.0.0          

  # accept "{"key":"value"} input                                    
  format json   

  # accept "json={"key":"value"} input                                    
  #format default
</source>                                               
<match **>                                              
  @type file                                            
  @id   output1                                         
  path         /fluentd/log/data.*.log                  
  symlink_path /fluentd/log/data.log                   
  format json                                           
  append       true                                     
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d                              
  time_slice_wait   10m                                 
  time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z                     
</match>
```

I have tried using regex or to modify data by nginx. Regex is not possible due to encoded and complex data and did not find way how to modify POST data with nginx (also this is bad way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ill answer myself. After trying a lot of configurations (and hours of reading official documentations of fluentd/nginx and blogs) I decided to create plugin (http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-development#parser-plugins). I have ended with this solution:

1. Parser plugin

   ```
   module Fluent
     class TextParser
       class CMXParser < Parser
         # Register this parser
         Plugin.register_parser("parser_CMX", self)

         config_param :format_hash, :string, :default => "data" #  delimiter is configurable with " " as default

         def configure(conf)
           super
         end

         # This is the main method. The input "text" is the unit of data to be parsed.
         def parse(text)
           text = WEBrick::HTTPUtils.parse_query(text)
           record = JSON.parse(text[@format_hash])
           yield nil, record
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Config for Fluentd

   ```
   <source>                                
     @type http                            
     port 24224                            
     bind 0.0.0.0                          
     body_size_limit 32m                   
     keepalive_timeout 5s                  
     format parser_CMX
   </source>                     

   <match **>                            
     @type file                          
     @id   output1                       
     path         /fluentd/log/data.*.log
     symlink_path /fluentd/log/data.log  
     format json                         
     append       true                   
     time_slice_format %Y%m%d            
     time_slice_wait   10m               
     time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z   
   </match>
   ```

I think there is space to implement this to core code, becouse base in_http script does the same thing, except it use only hardcoded string "params['json']". It can use new variable like "format_hash"/"format_map" that can contains map for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_http

This article shows accepted formats.

> How can i config fluentd to accept it same way?

It means do you want to parse `data={"k":"v"}` with `format json`?
If so, it can't.